# Is the source code for built in data types available anywhere?

Tags: c#

I am interested in accessing the source code used to develop built-in data types such as Int or String, is that code somewhere publically accessible or is it privately held somewhere by Microsoft. I am curious how that structure works. Also if it is hidden, what is the process for hiding code, is it encapsulation of some sort?

Comment: Google "referencesource" along with the full type name to see [`System.String`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs) and [`System.Int32`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/int32.cs) for example.

Comment: There's a duality to these types. One the one side, the intrinsic functionality is implemented by the processor, and the JIT compiler generates processor instructions for operations on them, such as multiplying `int`s. On the other side, you have the implementation of the methods overridden from `System.Object`, which are `GetHashCode`, `Equals`, and `ToString`. Those implement the "derived from Object" aspect of the types and are in the open-source runtime code on GitHub.

Comment: Here: https://source.dot.net/ But the primitive types are generally implemented at a lower level than C#.

Comment: I'm voting to keep open because this seems to asking for source code, which is analogous to asking for official documentation. ([link to guidance on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417732/11107541)).